# How to layer UIButtons and SpriteNodes

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, sprite-kit, uibutton

Ok so I'm wondering how to layer UIButtons & SpriteNodes so that my SpriteNodes are on the top of the UIButtons. Also, my UIButtons are on a Scroll View I created. Help would be nice!!

Code:

```
 let trunk = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Trunk")

    trunk.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    trunk.zPosition = 55
    self.addChild(trunk)

    let frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: frame)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height*4)
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = false
    self.view?.addSubview(scrollView)


    let buyButton1 = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    buyButton1.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 70, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/5, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/6)

    let image1 = UIImage(named:"Buy999Button")



     buyButton1.setImage(image1, forState: .Normal)
     buyButton1.addTarget(self, action: "something", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    buyButton1.layer.zPosition = 1
    scrollView.addSubview(buyButton1)
    scrollView.layer.zPosition = 1
    scrollView.sendSubviewToBack(scrollView)
```

Answer (score 0):

SKView is a UIView in itself. All the SpriteKit nodes are members of the SKView and contained in it. You can only change the draw order of views but not their contents.

SpriteKit nodes aren't views to begin with but drawn onto an OpenGL frame buffer managed by the SKView. From the perspective of Cocoa an SKView is a single view with no subviews in it.

Simply put: Nodes are technically incompatible to views.

Note: 
You could get a Sprite node to act like a button using `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Something like:

```
if (gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture) {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.neededSprite.frame, [self convertPoint:[sender locationInView:self.view] toNode:self]);
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: This question is request in Swift , you've answered in objective-c

Comment: And this answer doesn't even answer what I asked.. I asked how to layer SpriteNodes & UIButtons